# Hyperledger composer peer to peer connection not establishing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

We have established a business network using Hyperledger composer and created participant card by creating peers.

When we try to connect the peer to a different machine in the local after importing participant card then I'm getting the following error

> Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to
>   enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed
>   with errors [[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]

Business network is created in the mac machine and both machine are connected in the same wi-fi. Please help us to establish connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection profile that you are using. See [documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/connectionprofile). By default, the connection profile assumes that you are running everything on the same machine by using `localhost` as the `HOST`.

If you are using the basic Fabric network in the [single organisation tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org), you can make use of their script to point the machines to the correct IP address or host domain by running the following command to generate the peer admin card with the correct connection profile

```sh
./createPeerAdminCard.sh  --host {{HOST}}
```

Remember to replace `{{HOST}}` with the correct IP address or host domain like `192.168.1.1` or `fabric-endpoint.example.com`.

Once you have the correct connection profile in the peer admin card, all other business network cards generated will have the same connection profile and it would work.