# changing the hostnames to docker resolvable hostnames in composer

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am setting up a composer rest server with google authentication according to the following tutorial:
[Using Google OAUTH2.0 with a REST server](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest)

It works fine. However, after creating each participant, I need to change the hostnames to represent the docker resolvable hostnames. for example :

1-Adding participant:

```
   composer participant add -c admin@trade-network -d '{"$class":"org.example.trading.Trader","tradeId":"trader1", "firstName":"Jo","lastName":"Doe"}'

composer identity issue -c admin@trade-network -f jdoe.card -u jdoe -a "resource:org.example.trading.Trader#trader1"
composer card import -f jdoe.card
```

2- Changing the hostnames:

```
sed -e 's/localhost:7051/peer0.org1.example.com:7051/' -e 's/localhost:7053/peer0.org1.example.com:7053/' -e 's/localhost:7054/ca.org1.example.com:7054/'  -e 's/localhost:7050/orderer.example.com:7050/'  < $HOME/.composer/cards/jdoe@trade-network/connection.json  > /tmp/connection.json && cp -p /tmp/connection.json $HOME/.composer/cards/jdoe@trade-network/
```

This way is fine for quickly resolving the hostnames. But I was wondering if there is a better way that I don't need to manually run the 2nd command each time that I add a participant. Ideally,  I want to set the correct hostnames for all the future participants that will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed there is a much cleaner way to do it than your second command. The most efficient way to do it is when you set-up the peer admin card at the very beginning. When you first set up the Fabric network in the [Installing the development environment](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/installing/development-tools.html) tutorial, you used the command `./createPeerAdminCard.sh` to generate the peer admin card at the step **Controlling your dev environment**. This is where you have generated the *very first* connection profile upon which all other business network cards are based.

What you need to do is to set the correct hostnames at this step using the `--host` flag (this flag is not very properly documented but I have discovered it in the [source code here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/blob/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/createPeerAdminCard.sh))

```sh
./createPeerAdminCard.sh  --host {{HOST}}
```

Of course you remember to replace `{{HOST}}` with the correct hostname like `fabric-endpoint.example.com:8080`.

Comment: By the way a related question was asked here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931969/hyperledger-composer-peer-to-peer-connection-not-establishing/55581514#55581514